# All pictures is zooming

Tags: javascript, html, css

All the pictures on my website is zooming in, and I cannot figure out where in the code it is. The second slide on my [index](http://roulettesuite.com/index.php) page is the same as this one:

[image: Index page picture], but my legs are cut of etc. It is in general on all my page, where the pictures are doing it. Does anybody have an idea where that could be through the inspect window? I am not quite sure if the JavaScript is controlling some of this?

Another example is this [page](http://roulettesuite.com/personlighed.php), which have a `min-height: 350px;` on the banner. The original picture is looking like this, and should fit that size of the banner:

[image: Second Example]

This is the CSS for the banner on the index page:

```
slider-banner-container,
.slider-revolution-5-container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
}

.slider-banner-fullscreen,
.slider-banner-fullwidth {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.slider-banner-container ul.slides,
.slider-revolution-5-container ul.slides {
  display: none;
}

/*Spinner*/
.tp-loader.spinner2 {
  background-color: #999;
}

/*Captions*/
.tp-caption {
  z-index: 5;
}

.tp-caption a,
.tp-caption a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.tp-caption a.btn-gray,
.tp-caption a.btn-gray:hover {
  color: #333333;
}

.caption-box {
  max-width: 540px;
  color: #ffffff;
  white-space: normal;
  padding: 20px;
  border: none;
}

.caption-box h2 {
  color: #ffffff;
}

/*text rotator*/
.tp-caption .text-rotator {
  min-width: 580px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.light-translucent-bg.caption-box h2,
.light-translucent-bg.caption-box p {
  color: #333333;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.caption-box:after {
  z-index: -1;
}

.slideshow .dark-translucent-bg:not(.caption-box),
.slideshow .light-translucent-bg:not(.caption-box) {
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0 !important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: The width of the image is what you need to consider. If a screen is very wide then the image will stretch to accommodate it, but if the height is fixed then the image will start to become cropped. Maybe you could select images with the important parts in a central position, which will still look ok when cropping occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your slider works as it should. Resize your screen and you will notice that you will see the whole image in some sizes. Get different images like ovokuro suggested. 
For the second image what you are looking for is the min-height that is restricting the height. Try increasing the size and pushing the image down.

```
.banner.parallax, .banner.light-translucent-bg, .banner.dark-translucent-bg, .banner.default-translucent-bg {
    min-height: 350px;
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. I will try to look at that. I was just thinking if there was a div there was not closed or something. On the background picture in the mainpage, there is an arrow there is pointing down(in the bottom of the background picture). On desktop and up, that arrow is cut in half, where as on Ipad and down the arrow is there.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS property "background-size: contain;" if you want to show completely the image in your wrapper for the slides

```
.img-class{
    background-image: url(/images/banner1-desktop.jpg);
    background-size: contain;
}
```